# cordovaoauth.instagram return only token

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, instagram, profile, ngcordova

I am trying to login using istagram authentication; I am using ionic with angularjs and ngCordova oauth

```
$cordovaOauth.instagram("CLIENT_ID", ["basic","comments", "relationships"]).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

my console outputs only access_token. Where can I get user infomation? According to instagram developer site, return data should be:

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "..."
    }
}
```

but my return data is only :

```
{ access_token: 'XXXXX.XXXXX.1dd5c12d18c94905XXXXXXXXXXXXX' }
```

Comment: Not sure, but it might be a security problem for you to post your `acces_token` to this site. If so you'll probably want to get a new one as asap as possible.

Comment: thanks your advice!!